# Google task integration in android application

Tags: android, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

I am trying to integrate google task in android to store and retrieve task from google task, it is my first experience working on google task does any one of you have integrated google task or know way to do it ...

Answer (score 1):

Did you skipped the official documentation?
[https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/firstapp](http://Google%20Task%20Integration)

Just follow the steps given above oen by one and you're done . In case you are struck somewhere, then share the code.
**UPDATE:**
This is a detailed link for android:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/quickstart/android